# Show websites html in 3D view

Tags: firefox, 3d

I remember that it was possible to show the HTML of websites in 3D, e.g. all the containers were visible in 3 dimensions and you could rotate the view to see which containers are above other containers and so on. But I can't find the feature anymore. Was it removed?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Edge now has this feature:

[image: 3d Feature]

Answer (score 2):

This feature was available in Mozilla Firefox.

It's no longer available : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/3D_View

Update: The Microsoft Edge (chromium) team just announced this feature in their browser.
Check : https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2020/01/23/debug-z-index-3d-view-edge-devtools/ for more informations.

Comment: Aww, why did they removed it? Do you know if there is a way to install it again without having to download the old version?

Comment: Humm, nope. I don't know why they removed it. Maybe maintenance costs. I don't think you can easily find this feature again. Maybe in a JS project somewhere.